# Export an Android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, google-play

I want to export my Android project in order to publish on Google Play. It got exported successfully.

look at these lines of code:

```
GsonSyncPathResolverModel gsonSyncPathResolverModel = new GsonSyncPathResolverModel(new GsonBuilder());
            String TAG = "SyncPathReslover";

            HttpResponse licenceManagementResponse = Client.get(REST_URL.GETSynchURLResolver(customerID));
            int responseCode = licenceManagementResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(licenceManagementResponse.getEntity());
            Log.e(TAG, "response " + responseString);
            System.out.println(responseString);
            responseString=responseString.replace("{\"GetOrganizationInformationByOrganizationNumberResult\":\"[{","{");
            responseString=responseString.replace("}]\"}","}");
            responseString=responseString.replace('\\', Character.MIN_VALUE);
            responseString=responseString.replaceAll(""+Character.MIN_VALUE,"");

            System.out.println("#zzz "+responseString);

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                // syncPathResolver
                licenceManagementResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
                SyncPathResolverModel syncPathResolverModel = gsonSyncPathResolverModel.parseJSON(responseString);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from Server:  Organization ID:" + syncPathResolverModel.getObjectEntry_ID());
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from Server:  Sync Path:" + syncPathResolverModel.getSyncServiceURL());
```

When I run the project directly from the eclipse, The last line of code works fine, and print out the proper value.

but when I use the exported .apk file,

```
Log.e(TAG, "Response from Server:  Organization ID:" + syncPathResolverModel.getObjectEntry_ID());
Log.e(TAG, "Response from Server:  Sync Path:" + syncPathResolverModel.getSyncServiceURL());
```

These two lines print out `null`.

Can you help me what is the problem with exporting the .apk file?

It seems that the gson.jar library does not work when I signed the .apk file

Comment: First: you can't install an unsigned apk, what you mean is you installed the apk that is automatically signed with your debug key. Second: do you get any errors from your json parsing you do right before?

Comment: When you run from eclipse, do you run it on an emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: Do you use Gson from it source code or as a .jar?
If you are not already doing it I definitely recommend you to use it as a .jar file (and be sure that it is included to your build path).

Comment: @WarrenFaith, no I did not receive any error when I run it from eclipse, or as you said with my debug key.

Comment: @nicopico, I run it on a real device, and look at the log in the console.

Comment: @lethargicpanda, I used json library as .jar file.

Comment: When you log `responseString`, is it the expected value in both cases?

Comment: I would recommend using the build.xml file and ant to create a release APK.

Comment: @Nick, When I use the debug key, everything is fine, but when I export the project, and install the generated .apk file, the response from the server will be null.

Comment: `responseString` couldn't be completely null or else the calls to `.replace()` would fail. What's the actual value of `responseString` when you export the app?

Comment: no the responseString is not null. this will be null : syncPathResolverModel.getObjectEntry_ID()

Comment: _When I use the debug key, everything is fine, but when I export the project, and install the generated .apk file, the response from the server will be null._

Did you try to ping another server with the apk signed with the release key?

Comment: Another question: do you enable proguard when you sign your apk?

Comment: @lethargicpanda Yes progaurd is enabled. (proguard.config=proguard.cfg). regarding your first question: no I used the same server. It seems that the signed .apk can not recognize the external .jars such as json.jar

Comment: I don't have your exact project configuration in front of me, but from my understanding, without Gson.jar you wouldn't be able to import and instantiate `GsonSyncPathResolverModel` and then call
`gsonSyncPathResolverModel.parseJSON(responseString);`

To me the issue is in the server response. The question you should solve is Why do you get `responseString` null when your apk is signed.

Comment: @lethargicpanda, the responseString is not null. this will be null : syncPathResolverModel.getObjectEntry_ID(), So it could be a promlem with gsonSyncPathResolver. right?

Comment: Ha ok. But if you are able to compile your code and able to call `GsonBuilder` at the runtime without a NoClassDefFoundError or without a crash, it means that your .jar is included correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that json.jar file did not work properly after export the .apk files was related to enabling [ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837567/export-an-android-project-in-eclipse). So if I disable it or configure it properly, the .jar files will also work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project properties in Eclipse. Select Java Build Path, click the Order and Export tab. Make sure gson.jar is checked for export.